# How to iterate with the S tag a collection of Object

Tags: java, struts2

I have a collection of objects in a Struts2 action:

```
public class TakeClassification implements Action{

    List<Classificazione> classificazioni;

     @Autowired
     private Servizi servizi;

    public List<Classificazione> getClassificazioni() {
        return classificazioni;
    }

    public void setClassificazioni(List<Classificazione> classificazioni) {
        this.classificazioni = classificazioni;
    }


    public String execute() throws Exception {        
        classificazioni = servizi.getClassificazione();
        return SUCCESS;        
    }
    public void setServizi(Servizi servizi) {
        this.servizi = servizi;
    }
}
```

I want to iterate the elements of `classificazioni` in jsp with the s tag "iterator".
To specify I want to fill the items of a combobox with the expression `classificazioni.nome` that returns a String.

Comment: Are you using Struts 1.3 or Struts 2 ?
You can use JSTL (c:forEach tag) to iterate over a collection of data.

Comment: I know that i can use the c:forEach tag but since i'm using a <s:form>  i want to use a similar construct on the s tag.

Comment: If instead you need a drop down list, just use `<s:select>` inthe same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In struts tag you can use `<s:combobox>`.

See: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scombobox-combo-box-example/

It is the parameter **list**

Comment: Your list, **classificazioni** and in parameter **name** the attribute name the classificazioni!

see example:
`<s:combobox list="classificazioni" name="name"/>`